# How to link and pass absolutely no link juice

Tags: links, nofollow

How can I create a "link" from my site to other sites that passes no link juice or reputation whatsoever?  I'm not talking about nofollow links... I'm hoping to discover there's some way to create a text- or image-link that is simply not even recognized as a link by Google, but still functions identically to a normal "

Answer (score 3):

Nofollow *is* what you are looking for. It doesn't pass any link juice and google wont open or save them.

> In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not
>   transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially,
>   using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall
>   graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our
>   index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the
>   URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap.

[Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en)

Googles crawlers runs javascript and renders the page as close to what a web browser as it can. It will even [post form submits](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html).

I guess you could hide it behind a captcha since the whole idea of a captcha is that a robot should be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a redirector that is blocked in robots.txt.

Instead of linking to `http://example.com`, link to `/redirect?id=1` which does a database lookup based on the ID to get the URL and then issues a redirect.  Alter your *robots.txt* file to add:

```
Disallow: /redirect
```

That way users can use the link mostly like normal.   The only differences will be:  It may take a couple extra milliseconds on click to do the redirect.  Users won't be able to see the link URL destination using mouse-over.

Googlebot will have no idea where the link goes and will have no way of finding out.